# Create NUnit test cases "on the fly"

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I mean something like this.

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class SuccessTests
  {
    [Test]
    public void Something()
    {
       // Here code that dynamically would create additional Test Cases to the Fixture
    }

  }
```

Is that even possible once the test builder has been already initialized?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-planned, long-delayed, not-yet-started feature of NUnit.

We would probably not implement it from another test method but either at the fixture level (e.g. OneTimeSetUp) or with an attribute similar to TestCaseSource.

See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/7. Because it's an Epic, with sub-issues, you may need ZenHub to see everything there. Please contribute your ideas.

Bear in mind that the existing facilities of TestCaseSource attribute, even though we refer to them as "static", are able to add a variable number of cases at the time you load tests.